# Invoke native SQL Server function from Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Entity Framework 6 had [a way](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/registering-sql-server-built-in-functions-to-entity-framework-code-first) to register SQL Server Built-in Function with [DbFunction] attribute or [SQLFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Initially, as I understand, EF Core did *not* have this capability; but it seems from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2850) that it now exists via `EF.Functions`. However, I can't find any place that describes how to use it. Do I decorate implementation with an attribute and code fallback? Do I call the function in my code? Specifically, I want to call SQL Server `SOUNDEX()` function, but I am sure there are many other examples.

Comment: It seems like EF was short sited in this and trying to get a lot of this functionality back. You may be able to build up a class or whatever and adapt  [Raw store access API](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1862]) or [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) to your needs

Comment: Correct link: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1862 - for my limited needs (`Soundex()`) I just built a class in C#. While the number of rows returned is manageable it works just as well. But in a different place it won't work since it retrieves all 100K rows from the DB and does `where` in memory :( Let's see if there are any improvements in EF 2.0 - fortunately, my project can wait!

Comment: One of the reasons I generally don't use EF or LINQ for queries

Comment: @Felix The functionality does not exist in EF core yet. 
Tracking issue : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7368
Pull request on code changes: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/pull/7739

Comment: This functionality was added in EF Core 2.0 See the section Database scalar function mapping here -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/

Comment: Yes, thank you! We've been celebrating it over a month :)

Comment: Glad to hear you are getting use out of the feature.

Comment: The question was about *native* SQL functions, like LTRIM, etc.  The article referenced in this answer is about creating custom SQL functions...

Comment: It can also be used to map native methods which are not mapped by EF Core.  For Sql Server you need to explicitly set the Schema of the function to an empty string.

Comment: For searchers looking for 'How to call a function from ef core' (not created in ef core), this post is the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151773/best-practice-calling-scalar-functions-with-entity-framework-core-2-1 - Have removed my answer.

Comment: @HockeyJ - the post you referred to addresses a different situation. It solves the problem of encapsulating, say `SELECT SOUNDEX(lastname) FROM customer WHERE CustomerID = 25`; however, I want to get the function in the WHERE clause; e.g., `SELECT CustomerID, lastname, firstname FROM customer WHERE SOUNDEX(lastname) = 4321`. I don't think that post addresses that...

Comment: @Felix -Doesn't it work just using FromSql and putting the function in the plain text sql? I thought any sql put in FromSql ran as it would if you were running it in SSMS. You obviously still need to get the return type to match.