# Best practice calling scalar functions with Entity Framework Core (2.1)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I often need to call scalar functions that are defined on a SQL Server from my web applications (ASP.NET Core / EF Core). Since these functions are just simple helper functions and I also use a lot of them I use a general pattern for calling these scalar functions - with the help of the new query types available from EF Core 2.1.
Since I am relatively new to EF Core my question is if this pattern might cause problems and/or if there is a better solution or best practice for calling scalar functions. The solution works and I cannot observe any problems so far but for example I wondered if using the same query type for different functions might lead to unexpected values or weird behaviour due to caching/tracking behaviour, etc. within EF Core - it's more of a gut feeling.

So here's the pattern:
Instead of defining different entity types for every single scalar function I simply define one generic type:

```
public class PrimitiveDto<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

In my context class I register these types for every return type I expect from the scalar functions I want to use - so for all scalar functions returning 'int' the context class would have one additional entry like this:

```
public virtual DbQuery<PrimitiveDto<int>> BasicIntDto { get; set; }
```

For EF Core >= 3 it is:

```
public virtual DbSet<PrimitiveDto<int>> BasicIntDto { get; set; }
```

In every part of the application where I want to call a scalar function returning 'int' I simply use the same following pattern:

```
context.BasicIntDto.FromSql("SELECT <FUNCTION> AS Value")
```

By using this pattern I can call any number of functions the same way without defining additional types or extending the context class.

Please let me know if I could run into a trap through this pattern. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see any major problems with it, but you can probably refactor it a bit so that you don't have to provide the entire query on every call.  Making a property on the context that returns a `BasicDto<int>` for each function / proc, that accepts any arguments required, for example.

Comment: You're right - thanks for this idea.

Comment: Why don't you use [Database scalar function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping). Yes, it requires you extending the context class, but doesn't require additional types and provides reusability, intelisense support and compile time checking, as with regular LINQ and CLR methods.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Ivan Stoev - I must admit that I wasn't aware of this feature yet. But it turns out you can't call scalar function directly through this feature - you must start with an entity type and then can use these method stubs within the query (i.e. context.ENTITY.where(x => x.METHODSTUB()) ...). However they seem to be working on this (see https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9810). So again, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You could use `Enumerable.Single` method on result.

Comment: Mark G could you please provide additional information about that? Is this a different approach or do you simply mean I should call .Single() after .FromSql()?

Comment: @Grimm, correct.  Another option is to use ADO.NET by using [GetDbConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.getdbconnection) and using ExecuteScalar.

Comment: Mark G, I'm sorry that I have to ask again but what exactly is correct now?

Comment: Looks like [DbQuery is deprecated for EF Core 3](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15656), so it should be `DbSet<PrimitiveDto<int>>`.

Comment: That's true, just replace DbQuery<...> with DbSet<...> in this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems this feature has been left aside: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9810

An option is to wrap the functions calls in a static class using a small table which is never empty:

```
public static class DbFunctions
{
   public static decimal MyFunctionABC(int param1, int param2)
   {
       using (var db = new MyDbContext())
       {
        return db.table.Take(1).Select(t => MyDbContext.MyFunctionABC(x, y)).Single();
       }
    }
 }
```

Then you can call `DbFunctions.MyFunctionABC(x,y);`

Comment: I like this method, and used it in an alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68902584/6680521