# How to call a Scalar Function in Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

following [this article](http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/01/11/entity-framework-core-2-scalar-function-mapping/) I was trying to call an inside SQL Function into my application using Entity Framework Core

I created the static method in context, like this:

```
public class DbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    [DbFunction("FN_ENCRYPT", "DBO")]
    public static string FN_ENCRYPT(string ENC)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

after this, I get a little confused about how to call it, so I tried in this way (because its a static method, of course):

```
public string Encript(string word)
{
    return DbContext.FN_ENCRYPT(word);
}
```

but, guess what? I received a "nice" NotImplementedException :)

Can somebody help me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using the call itself it throws the exception because it actually executes the C# code. The reason it is recommended to throw an exception is exactly this, to avoid inadvertent use, ie by directly calling it. That signature will be interpreted by **the given LINQ provider** and translate into the proper SQL statements.

In MS [EF Core Database scalar function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping) :

> they can be used in LINQ queries and translated to SQL

Here is a working demo :

Model and DbContext

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB  { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext:DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options):base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    [DbFunction("CalculateAge", "dbo")]
    public static int CalculateAge(DateTime dob)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and use

```
public IActionResult GetAge(int employeeId)
    {
        var query = _context.Employees
                .Where(x => x.Id == employeeId)
                .Select(d =>new
                { 
                    Name=d.Name,
                    DOB=d.DOB,
                    Age= MyDbContext.CalculateAge(d.DOB)
                }).ToList();
        return Json(query);
    }
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it working in this way, but I still get a little confused because in DbContext you're using the class Employees just to call the DbFunction. In my case, there is no table attached to the function at all. Doesn't make sense have to call a Table (I tried every table in the database and it works).

Comment: Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate ....

Comment: In my case it is always throwing  throw new NotImplementedException();

Comment: See my answer to a similar question for how to call it directly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68902584/6680521

Answer (score 2):

While there is no option to call a scalar function that is not related to the existing entities by EF, it is still possible to do that this way using the existing EF's DB context:

```
using (DbCommand command = this.storageContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT dbo.YourFunc()";
    await this.storageContext.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();

    bool result = (bool)(await command.ExecuteScalarAsync());

    await this.storageContext.Database.CloseConnectionAsync();
    return result;
}
```

This one returns `bool`.