# How can call database function from asp.net core 3.1 from the controller class

Tags: asp.net-core

How can I call the sqlserver database function  dbo.EmpHrsEmpHrs() from the controller. Its return value is decimal. I want to store return value from the scalar function to the model class attribute EmpHrs. I have checked google but I couldnot find the proper solution to this question.

model class

```
Employee.cs
public int id{get;set;)
public string EmpName(get;set;)
public decimal EmpHrs(get;set;)
```

dbContext.Employee.EmpHrs = // Here we Should get the value from the scalar function

Answer (score 0):

You can add `[DbFunction("CalculateAge", "dbo")]` on your dbcontext, like below

```
public class MyDbContext:DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options):base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    [DbFunction("CalculateAge", "dbo")]
    public static int CalculateAge(DateTime dob)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can call the function by `DbContext.CalculateAge(...)`.

#### Related Blogs and Posts

[1. Entity Framework Core 2 – Scalar function mapping](https://anthonygiretti.com/2018/01/11/entity-framework-core-2-scalar-function-mapping/)

[2. How to call a Scalar Function in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713900/how-to-call-a-scalar-function-in-entity-framework-core)